# angular2 + webpack

Tags: angular2, webpack

Здравствуйте.

Даже не знаю как правильно озаглавить проблему и поэтому получилось невыразительно "angular2 + webpack"
Суть проблемы такова:

1. При сборке в режиме dev постоянно вываливается одна ошибка: HtmlWebpackPlugin не может найти index.html
2. При сборке в режиме prod собирается без ошибок, но потом, при попытке открыть index.html обычным браузером, пишет, что polifill.js и app.js не найдены. после удаления строки  из index.html, файлы polifill.js и app.js находятся, но тогда вываливается куча ошибок связанных с xhr и zone.js

   zone.js:2975 Failed to load "bla-bla-bla..." Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
3. если после prod сборки в папке /dist запустить ng serve, то всё запускается и выглядит так, как ожидалось, но только папка /dist тут же исчезает
   пути вроде все правильно прописал...
   прям, детектив какой-то.

Answer (score 0):

разобрался. проблема была комплексная:

1. не был указан webpack.config
2. я копировал из приложения созданного предварительно через ng и не исключил разные файлы типа test.ts и пр.